# Open terminal in XFCE from script and activate python virtualenv

Tags: python-3.x, bash, virtualenv, xfce

I try to open terminal in XFCE and activate python3 virtualenv using the following line in a bash script:

```
xfce4-terminal --working-directory=$HOME/path/to/project --maximize \
-e 'bash -c "source $HOME/path/to/project/venv/bin/activate; bash"'
```

The strange thing is that the virtualenv gets kind of activated since:

```
which python
```

shows the correct path to the virtualenv directory and the project seems to be working fine.

However I don't see the `(venv)` to the left from the shell prompt. Moreover, when I enter `deactivate` it complains that no such command can be found.

Is there a proper way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I created  a bash shortcut for this in my `/Users/username/.bash_profile` (I use mac; on linux use `Users/username/.bashrc` instead).

```
function pcd() {
    cd /Users/username/Code/"$1"_env/"$1"
    source ../env/bin/activate
    atom -a .
}
```

Where `project_env` is the root folder, which contains the `venv`, and the `project` folders (project folder is where code goes)

to execute this simply call `pcd project`

I don't know much about bash, so I can't really tell you why your code doesn't work.

Also, make sure you open a new terminal window after saving this.

Comment: But what about automatically opening xfce4-terminal? How do I tell the `xfce4-terminal` command to activate the virtualenv?